# Display timeline chart of activities timed to music for a group of performers

Tags: time-management, charts, music-composing

I would like to have a program with which I can create a timeline chart of moves and activities that happen synchronized with the rhythm of a background music; you can think to a dance routine involving multiple people doing different moves, for instance.

Think something like a timeline or [Gantt chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart) for instance, but on the time axis instead of having working days/hours I have the [measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_%28music%29) of the music. Or like a MIDI composer but without the notes.

Eventually I would like to be able to somehow play of the music back synchronized with descriptions of the activities appearing on the screen, to help during practice and making it easier to explain the routine to new members of a group of performers. Is there a program that can do all that? What would you suggest using that supports at least some of these features? I am considering abusing [Rosegarden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosegarden) or Excel, for instance, but I don't think they are the right tool for this job.

The software should be for Windows or Linux, preferably Linux. Let's not put a price limit for now.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at [MoviePy](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) which will let you combine video clips, images, text, soundtrack, etc. into a movie with whatever timings you need

- Gratis
- Cross Platform *including Windows & Linux*